# OnMouseDown function to remove disabled Attribute from buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a game that allows users to select which letters they want to use for the game. Each letter is a button identical to the one below, with `disabled = true`.

```
<button id = "a" disabled = "true" style={{ fontSize: '8vh', height: '100%', width: '8%', cursor: 'pointer' }} 
     onMouseDown={function () {
          var a= "A";
          addToDisplayList(a);
     }}>
     A
</button>
```

Before the user can select the letters, they must click the *Select Letters button* which resets the array that holds the selected letters and removes the disable attribute from all the letter buttons. The code for the Select Letters button is below.

```
<button id = "clear" style={{ fontSize: '8vh', height: '100%', cursor: 'pointer' }}
       onMouseDown={function () {
            setToZero();
            for(var i=0; i<letterList.length; i++){
                 document.getElementById(letterList.charAt(i)).removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
}}>
Select Letters
</button>
```

When I click Select Letters to remove the disabled attribute from all the letter buttons, they become ungreyed out and seem to be enabled. However when I click any of the letter buttons, they do not run their onMouseDown functions.

Comment: It might be easier to make your buttons call a function which checks whether the calling button is in the array of active buttons. Your select active letters would then only need to load this array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give that a try!

Comment: Please click up my comment if you appreciate it. Thank you.